# Element-wise maximum with key

Tags: python, numpy, key, max, elementwise-operations

is there a more efficient way to perform **element-wise** maximum **with key**?

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([-2, 2, 4, 0])
b = np.array([-3,-5, 2, 0])
c = np.array([ 1, 1, 1, 1])

mxs = np.empty((4,))
for i in range(4):
    mxs[i] = max([a[i], b[i], c[i]], key=abs)

>>> mxs
array([-3., -5.,  4.,  1.])
```

Unfortunately, `numpy.maximum` does not offer a `key` parameter, as it would be nice to be able to do something similar with:
`np.maximum.reduce([a,b,c])`

Comment: Are you just interested in the `key=abs` case or looking for a more general solution?

Comment: Primarily for the `abs` solution, but would be nice to see more general solutions too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
arr = np.array([a,b,c])
arr[np.argmax(np.abs(arr), axis=0), np.arange(arr.shape[1])]
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of giving key function as absolute make as integer function.

---

### Code

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([-2, 2, 4, 0])
b = np.array([-3,-5, 2, 0])
c = np.array([ 1, 1, 1, 1])

mxs = np.empty((4,))
for i in range(4):
   mxs[i] = max([a[i], b[i], c[i]], key=int)

print(mxs)
```